# R - row subsets of data frame based on all combinations of factor levels

Tags: r, subset

I'm trying to figure out the simplest way to do the following. I have a data frame `df` with `colnames(df) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")` where all the variables are encoded as factors. Given some arbitrary subset of variables, I want to generate all possible subsets of rows of `df` that can be generated based on all the possible combinations of factor levels of these variables.

So basically, I'm looking for a function `allSubsets` that takes a vector of column names as arguments (let's say `c("A", "E")` and returns a list of data frames. Let's say `levels(df$A)` are `a1, a2` and `levels(df$E)` are `e1, e2, e3`, then I want the function to generate a list of data frames (length  where elements correspond to :

`df[df$A == 'a1' & df$E == 'e1',]`

`df[df$A == 'a2' & df$E == 'e1',]`

`df[df$A == 'a1' & df$E == 'e2',]`

`df[df$A == 'a2' & df$E == 'e2',]`

`df[df$A == 'a1' & df$E == 'e3',]`

`df[df$A == 'a2' & df$E == 'e3',]`

I know of `expand.grid` but I'm not sure if that's the best way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `split` to get a `list`of `data.frame`s

```
lst1 <- split(df, df[c("A", "E")], drop = TRUE)
```